# Missing DLLs after Inkscape compilation

Tags: windows, mingw, inkscape

All

I've tried to compile Inkscape on Windows. It was successful. 
Except two things :

1. inkscape.exe is 14MB size is it Release or debuge version ? (btool -j4)
2. There are no dlls. I've copied them from devlibs/bin and had the error "Internal error". Inkscape didn't start.

What did i wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm dump.

I was looking for inkscape.exe in ./build
Full inkscape was in ./inkscape folder.

Sorry.